# How to create a new window like a message box?

Tags: tkinter

Hi guys hope you are doing well, i can't understand how to create in Tkinter a new window for example when i press a button that is like a message box, i mean creating a new window and i can't go back to the previous/main window until i close or press ok in the new window. How to simply create a new window and the user can't click the main window and can't go away until he close it just like happen in the message box ?? Thanks! Here is a basic starting code, how to bind this window that i'm talking about to the button?

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
button = Button(window,text="Click here")
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of dialog that takes control of the application is called "modal dialog". It can be implemented using the `grab_set` method.

```
from tkinter import *

def new_window():
    def close_window():
        dialog.grab_release()
        dialog.destroy()
    dialog = Toplevel(window)
    close = Button(dialog,text="close",command=close_window)
    close.pack()
    dialog.grab_set()
    

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
button = Button(window,text="Click here",command=new_window)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

This code creates a new Toplevel window when you press "Click here". That dialog will grab all the events for the current application until you click the close button which will release the grab.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot it's exactly what i was looking for it's the grab function that block in the dialog window, i mark your answer and upgrade

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

As @scotty3785 have mentioned above, you can use the `grab_set()` method to keep the focus on your toplevel window. But still the root window will be draggable. But reading the documentation, I came across `grab_set_global()` method.

> **w.grab_set_global()**
> Widget w grabs all events for the entire screen. This is considered impolite and should be used only in great need. Any other grab in force goes away.

*Reference: [Universal widget methods](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html)*

Although this is considered impolite, it does what you were trying to achieve here. Make sure to also set focus on the toplevel window:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def show_message():
    dialog = tk.Toplevel(root)

    close = tk.Button(dialog,text="close",command=dialog.destroy)
    close.pack()

    dialog.focus_set()
    dialog.grab_set_global()

button = tk.Button(root,text="Click here", command=show_message)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

### Alternate solution

Tkinter's `messagebox` widget can do what you are trying to achieve here. While the messagebox is visible, you won't be able to focus on the root window.

### Reference

- [tkinter.messagebox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html)

### Example

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

root = tk.Tk()

def dialog(*args):
    mb.showinfo("Dialog", "Hello World!")

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=dialog)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: test]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, that's great but in the message box i can't add more buttons, add images, input fields ecc it's only an info message, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Stefano9669 You are not wrong, you can't add widgets to tkinter Dialogs. Do note that you didn't provide this information in your question. So you can, instead, as @scotty3785 have mentioned above, use the `grab_set()` method to keep the focus on your toplevel window. But still the root window will be draggable. Since thats the default behavior of windows in window managers, in order to prevent that, I'm guessing you will have to `overrideredirect()` your root window and allow/deny dragging manually.

Comment: Yes my bad for not providing that information, thanks even for the overrideredirect() function later on i will try, an other important thing do you know when i open a new window for example with Toplevel, how to automatically focus the program in the new window? It's a detail but i notice that it's "over" the main window, i hope you understand my question

Comment: @Stefano9669 consider checking my answer once again, I have provided a bit more info on how you can create a dialog which prevents access to root window completely.

Comment: Ok thanks, i upvoted your answer

Comment: I'm having trouble with the status bar of the main window, i don't really like the overrideredirect() method but thanks anyway, do you know ho to simply disable the status bar of a window? Like is present but not allow clicks at all

Comment: @Stefano9669 Since the titlebar is managed by your window manager, its not possible to change it's state. Instead you will have to use `overrideredirect()` and create your own custom titlebar. Your window will also lose the dragging, iconifying and expanding features.